# Django show message parameters in HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: django, redirect, httpresponse, message

I'm working on a basic web page that asks for a user's name and phone number, and if successfully submitted, it will redirect to a page that shows the user's name and phone number. I kept getting a 403 error when I try to submit the name and phone number. Here is the code:

This is the code in views.py:

```
def homeform(request):
 if request.method == "POST":
form = PhoneForm(request.post)
if form.is_valid():
    cd = form.cleaned_data
    messages.success(request, "%s, you have recorded your phone number as %d. Thanks for the update.") %(cd["name"],cd["phone"])
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')
 else:
    form = PhoneForm()
 return render_to_response('phone_form.html',{'form': form})

def success(request):
  return render_to_response('success.html',{'messages': messages})
```

This is the code in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
('^home/$',homeform),
('^success/$', success),
```

)

Here is the html file I'm using for the success function in the view:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Success</title>
<head>
<body>
  {% if messages %}
  <ul class="messages">
  {% for message in messages %}
  <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your question title, but if you're getting a 403, it's most likely a CSRF error (which you would have seen). You should be posting the view that POSTs, not the success view/template.

Add `{% csrf_token %}` inside the `<form>` tags on any POST forms or django will complain of CSRF errors.

Comment: Yes, this has nothing to do with messages.

Comment: @Yuji, thanks for the reply. The following is the code in phone_form.html.
  7         <form action='' method="post">
  8         {% csrf_token %}
  9         <table>
 10         {{form.as_table}}
 11         </table>
 12         <input type='submit' value="Submit">
 13         </form>
Also, according the 403 error message, I changed the render_to_response line in the view (success) function and used  "return render_to_response('success.html', {'messages': messages}, context_    instance=RequestContext(request))" instead. 

But I still get the same error message.

Comment: Make sure the rendered output contains an actual token. Even if you have RequestContext, you may not have the csrf context processor in your settings.py but for sure you should check the output HTML for the token